# Is there an equivalent to texlive-science package on Mac?

Tags: texlive, tinytex

I need to install several packages from [texlive-science](https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-science). However, I don't know how many or which ones, since every time I compile my document it says another package is missing. I could install one by one; however, names are not simple to deduce. Take `algorithm` for instance:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `algorithm.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

When I try to install `algorithm`, I get an error:

```
$ sudo tlmgr install algorithm
Password:
tlmgr: package repository https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package algorithm not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

It happens because the package real name to install is `algorithms`, with an `s` at the end:

```
$ sudo tlmgr install algorithms
tlmgr: package repository https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: algorithms [4k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
```

Hence my question: is there a way to install a package equivalent to texlive-science on Mac? How? I am using TeX Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022) if it helps.

Comment: Not what you asked for, but anytime you get that message, the following is very useful: `tlmgr search --file algorithm.sty`.

Comment: Did you use a dsitribution to install TeX, like MacTex? If so, some of them provide a console, e.g. https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console on Windows. I can configure it such that it asks for permission to download missing packages. So, whenever I put a \usepackage and something is missing, it asks for an OK (and then sometimes can't stop downloading dependencies)

Comment: What exactly did you install in the first place? You tagged this with `mactex`, if you installed MacTeX you should already have everything contained in `txlive-science`

Comment: you can install a collection such as `collection-mathscience` using tlmgr

Comment: @gusbrs that is super useful. Thank you!

Comment: @daleif I installed [TinyTex](https://yihui.org/tinytex/), an R package that install a lightweight version of TexLive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusNunes Unless you are short on disk space, you could install a complete texlive from tug.org and never again(*) run into problems with missing packages.

Comment: as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says tiny tex generates more work in the end, installing texlive-full doesn't take up that much space by modern standards and saves all these issues

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and David Carlisle yes, I agree with you both. I use TinyTex because I teach R and R Markdown on my classes, for undergrads that are using LaTeX for the first time, in Windows, Linux, and macOS. So I need a solution that I can test on my laptop and it works for everyone. TinyTex was the least painful for me and them. But I agree that, sometimes, TinyTex generates more work in my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really do not have space to install a full texlive, you can install a collection such as `collection-mathscience` using tlmgr which should give you most of the packages in those subject areas.